# Is it a bad idea to display the F-word on my GitHub profile?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, unprofessional-behavior

Ordinarily, this would seem like a no-brainer, but maybe not...

I am a college student currently applying for a summer internship at a company where I would be doing a lot of software development with a team of interns. As part of the application process, I gave them a link to my GitHub profile.

As a hobbyist developer, I've worked on a large variety of projects, including writing a shell for the esoteric programming language [BrainF***](https://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck) (except the actual name doesn't contain '*'s). This shell showcases some of my best work as a hobbyist developer. It's written entirely in cross-platform C code, uses the GNU Build System, and is the only project on my page which has these traits. On the flip side, it's also the only project I've ever released under the somewhat vulgar [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) license agreement.

Naturally, as soon as I realized I would have to share my repository link with the recruiting team, I made my BrainF*** shell a private project, thus hiding it from public view, but I'm still not sure that this was the best idea. Should I leave the project hidden to seem more professional, or should I make it public again to showcase my diverse skill set?

**UPDATE:**
I decided to hide the repository during the candidacy process. Whether this made any difference or not I'll never know, but I did get the job, and I've now made the repo public again.

Comment: Is the shell in BF or C?

Comment: @Aoradon it's a BF interpreter/shell, but it's written in C.

Comment: Can't you simply rename this... whatever it is?

Comment: @joeqwerty there's a chance I could censor it, but BrainF*** is the proper name of the programming language I designed the shell to operate on, so renaming it to something else would make it much more difficult to understand what it actually does.

Comment: If you're sharing it with potential employers you should consider it an extension of your resume, and you wouldn't use the F-word on that now, would you?

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based.  For what it is worth my opinion is that (1) you should leave that hidden and (2) stop all development in something called that. Credit to you for figuring that out before providing your credentials to BAH. For the record I'm not offended by that word, but some people are and people who *are not* offended might question your level of professionalism *if they see it*. For what it is worth I have a friend whose personal email is 'eating garbage' and he had that on his resume and got a fortune 500 job... so, maybe it won't hurt.

Comment: What about calling it by a euphemism like "BrainSnafu"? (With explanation, of course)

Comment: Or, just call it "an esoteric language with an impolite name" and link the wikipedia article?

Comment: The reason it is called Brainfuck is not to curse at people, so there is no need to censor it. Have you taken a moment to look at how programs in that language look? If you have, the name makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Brandin I'm well aware. I wrote and tested a fully functioning shell for it, after all. I'm just concerned that my potential employers may not share that view...

Comment: FWIW when I read the title my knee-jerk reaction was "absolutely, unless they are talking about BF"

Comment: Do you have to tag the language?

Comment: You could just make references to "an [esoteric programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language)" on all of your public pages.

Comment: Just a thought, but you could turn it into a DerpPlusPlus interpreter which is functionally equivalent to BF, but has a name far less likely to rustle corporate feathers.

Comment: For what it's worth: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck.

Comment: I don't see how this is any more "opinion-based" than 99% of the questions on this site...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leave it hidden.

It really is not appropriate in a corporate business setting and it is even worse to have as a first impression.

Some people might not mind but others might be completely offended and repulsed by it.  You have no way of knowing how someone will react so the safer bet is to not go there.

Comment: Personally, after 20 years in the industry, I would never choose to work for a manager who is offended by a good bit of BF.  On the other hand, I probably can afford to be more picky about my employers than a new grad can.   In your situation,  I'd probably wait for the interview question about personal projects to mention you've written an interpreter shell for "an esoteric language with an impolite name".  Use the reaction to judge how much more you should share.

Comment: @AShelly good point but you gotta remember in some corporate environments even opening that page on a web browser can activate their IT blocking systems and cause problems about why they were trying to access a website with that in it.  It is best to err on the side of caution.

Comment: What @solarflare says especially true for companies like the one to which OP has applied.

Comment: @solarflare even more reason not to work for a company that has such mechanisms! ;)

Comment: @AShelly I understand being picky, but then again, remember that applications go first through the recruiting department, they might be non-technical and not get the underlying context. It might suffice if they don't kick the application out but sort it at the bottom of the pile because they would need to spend time to clarify / validate that initial bad feeling. So I'd agree with solarflare to not include this initially. Though perhaps at a stage where you know who you deal with, can gauge their humour/acceptance level and when you feel you really need to show them this.

Comment: -1 Brainfuck is the proper name of the programming language, not something OP named, and demonstrates their programming capabilities as, in OP's words, it "showcases some of my best work". You are choosing to hide it based on speculative concerns that management will be offended by a word, vs the upside of realising how talented the OP is. It acts as a good filter for the programmer too, because do you really want to work for an employer that discriminates based on the name of a programming language you used?

Comment: @PascLeRasc but very few people are going to go to the trouble to try and read it. They will not understand the code you put in there.

Comment: @PascLeRasc, ok, well when you find someone hiring for a BF developer position, go for it.

Comment: Everyone is missing one important point: HR will see this as well, do you think they will share the same enthusiasm as a developer?

Comment: I think this person should leave it, but clean up the docs leaving the swear only visible when strictly necessary.

A good strategy is to list the repo under an appropriate name "Chef Cyanide's BF shell", then when you are discussing with _technical_ interviewers, you can mention the repository and note that it's probably the best showcase of your capabilities. You don't have to swear, you can talk about it intelligently. They may or may not ask to see it.

People browsing you git* without you mentioning it will either be switched on enough to investigate, or just pass it by.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  The arguments people are making here remind me of my own debate about whether (as a guy) to cut off my long hair years ago.  _Should_ it make a difference to people?  No.  _Does_ it make a difference to people?  Most definitely yes.  Is it worth limiting my options and my salary to keep it?  When framed that way, I made the pragmatic decision.  It wasn't a principle worth making a fuss over.  Nor is this, when balanced against people who won't know what the language is; all they'll see is the inappropriate language.

Comment: @solarflare I very much doubt if HR will open the guys github as they wont have a clue what it is. It's far more likely to be other developers who are less likely to care.

Comment: @ayrtonclark you're probably right but its still an unnecessary risk

Answer (score 25):

**It's the official name of the programming language.**

List it as such in quotes and explain that it's an external language you write code in.

**No need to hide it nor to censor it.**

Comment: Great idea but what would a HR staff member think?

Comment: @solarflare if they can read, they'd understand.What should they think? It wasn't OP's decision to name the language.If not, I wager OP probably doesn't want to work there anyways...Also quite frankly, outside of the U.S. and maybe Canada, that "F-word", it's not that big of a deal.So it depends where OP applies.

Comment: I'm in Australia and outside of work the F word (amongst friends at least) is part of my everyday vocabulary. But in the corporate world it is a huge no-no. If I were to receive an application with that being showcased as a great skill I'd honestly think the applicant was an idiot and probably not a good fit for the corporate office environment.  Smaller companies might not mind.  It is highly subjective.  I've seen a guy get knocked back on his application because his email address was 'flexit@...'.  He was a bodybuilder and was deemed to be unprofessional (ie an idiot).

Comment: @solarflare it's true that in work environments that is to be avoided (though only to cover their behinds from lawsuits mostly) but OP is not throwing it into the conversation. It's the official name of a programming language and as such is (should be by rational minds) exempt from being a curse word hurled at you. I agree though there might be people who think otherwise but I'm convinced they're the "idiots" as you say, for dismissing a developer who is capable enough to work with such a language...oh and they need to grow up...

Comment: he CHOSE this language to work on.  He CHOSE to showcase it.  He wasn't forced into it.  There's plenty of similar languages to play with and showcase if the aim is to impress potential employers.  BrainF*** would really only be suitable to bring up either after you get the job or *maybe* in a face to face interview if you're sure the interviewers are like-minded engineers. Putting it into a portfolio and making it part of your application just shows you *might* be an idiot which unfortunately some employers/HR might see as a liability to the company.

Comment: The fact that it's the official name of the language doesn't magically turn it into a non-offensive name.

Answer (score 12):

Definitely keep it. It's an excellent demonstration of your software engineering skills, and a filter for companies you don't want to work with. You obviously like esoteric programming, don't you want to be with like-minded coworkers?

Answer (score 4):

I say leave it.  Programming is programming, whether you use Java or C or Golang or Brainfuck.  It shows what you can do.  In fact, programming in Brainfuck is arguably better because of how limited the language is and how difficult it is to do even the most simple of operations (iirc "Hello World" is like a 50-line program in Brainfuck).

If you would like to mitigate the possible repercussions of having the F-word on your GitHub, you can add a link to the Brainfuck website in your README files for your Brainfuck projects.  Then, if some recruiter wants to know why you have the F-word on your GitHub, they can click the link and look at it.  To be honest, if a recruiter is going to pass over an engineer capable of working in Brainfuck over the fact that they chose a language called Brainfuck to work in, that recruiter is going to miss out on a lot of very capable talent.  I personally once wrote a Brainfuck interpreter (in Java), although I regrettably never published it to my GitHub.

Comment: Technically, it's still only a one line program... ;)

Comment: It's a one-line program in the same way that the entirety of the Google codebase is a one-line program.  One, VERY LONG, line ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Hide it.  Here’s why…

It’s a risk/reward scenario where the main considerations are:  who will see it; how will they react; and what will it accomplish?

Odds are resume crawlers, recruiters and HR people will never dig into GitHub and hiring managers lack the time to do hours of research.  They have multiple candidates, a day job and you already know they’re short-handed.  So yes, it’s unlikely it will be seen before you get to talk to someone and frame it first.  But of those who might, you run some risk of being weeded out before the content itself is ever considered.  So there’s little benefit to having it available.

To how would someone react, that first impression won’t be forgotten.  Yes, most won’t care, but until you get a chance to have conversations, why run any risk of removing yourself from consideration.

As to what it will accomplish, its esoteric nature makes it unlikely they’ll dig in to really the beauty of your accomplishment.  So their main takeaway will be the name of the language.

Once you can talk with them you can frame it as you like.  “I wrote this really cool piece, but should warn you the name of the language is indelicate.”  Then offer to allow them access as you see fit.  Until you get a call, your goals are to stand out **quickly** and not weed yourself out.  Once an actual conversation is opened, you have some freedom.  Until that time, tiny things can take you out of the running before your actual skills are ever considered.